# How to get LatLng coordinates of a point feature?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This seems like such a ridiculously trivial thing, but I am stumped.

I have a Point Feature in the Google Maps API that I would like to get the coordinates of:

```
g = centroids.getFeatureById("Tift").getGeometry()
g.getType()
>>"Point"
```

I have tried:

```
g.location
> undefined
```

I can see the coordinates when I enter

```
g.get()
```

But can't find a way to access them.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I assume you are talking about a GeoJSON file loaded on a [google.maps.DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), but it doesn't say that anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a GeoJSON file loaded on a [google.maps.DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer)

[.get()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Point) should return a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object

To get its coordinates use:

- .lat() for latitude
- .lng() for longitude
- .toUrlValue(6) for a comma separated string in the format latitude, longitude with 6 decimal points of resolution.